# ¿Como puedo acceder a los elementos de un array y asociarlos a variables distintas?

Tags: php, html, array

Espero que esten bien y saludables. Como siempre me dirijo a esta comunidad en busqueda de ayuda en un proyecto.

Consiste en tomar los datos de un array e imprimirlos por separado, o sea, almacenarlos en variables distintas.

El script PHP que llama a una API y obtiene el array es el siguiente:

```
function llamadaApi()
{
    $content = file_get_contents('https://www.ejemplo.com/soap/ApiServiceHTTP.php?method=getPilotList&idVA=xxx');
    $jsonData = json_decode($content, true);
    return($jsonData);
}
```

Bien, eso lo unico que hace es llamar a un servicio el cual nos devuelve un array (que es pasado a formato array con el segundo parametro de `json_decode`())

Una vez explicado eso pasamos con la segunda parte del script:

```
$almacen = llamadaApi();

    $name = var_dump($almacen[0]["name"]);
    $country = var_dump($almacen[0]["country"]);
    $avatar = var_dump($almacen[0]["avatar"]);
    $imageRating = var_dump($almacen[0]["imageRating"]);
    $callsign = var_dump($almacen[0][0]["callsing"]);
    $totalHoursFlights = var_dump($almacen[0][0]["totalHoursFlights"]);
    $ivao = var_dump($almacen[0]["ivao"]);
```

Y un ejemplo del array es este:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ernor] => 0
    [created] => 2020-05-07 00:00:26
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1023
                    [name] => Juan Camilo V.
                    [country] => CO
                    [avatar] => https://www.uesva.com/avatar/icons.php?o=17&i=1023_sheacyPnckHzoGacTAkJDwPFRjZMRp1588229451
                    [scoreRating] => 104,00
                    [pilotRating] => Estudiante
                    [imageRating] => https://www.uesva.com/avatar/icons.php?o=16&i=91_kYxDuERnbE1587976704
                    [lastLoginDate] => 2020-05-01
                    [lastLoginTime] => 06:35:11
                    [UesvaRegisteredDate] => 2020-03-29
                    [UesvaRegisteredTimee] => 21:10:49
                    [ivao] => 494761
                    [vatsim] => 1458554
                    [dataAirline] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [callsign] => AVC100
                            [totalFlights] => 2
                            [totalFlightsRegular] => 2
                            [totalFlightsCharter] => 0
                            [totalFlightsEvent] => 0
                            [totalFlightsTour] => 0
                            [totalFlightsTransfer] => 0
                            [totalHoursFlights] => 1:08:57
                            [totalHoursOnline] => 2:12:44
                            [totalMilesFlown] => 440
                            [totalPassengersCarried] => 279
                            [totalPassengersFirstClass] => 0
                            [totalPassengersBusiness] => 19
                            [totalPassengersEconomic] => 260
                            [totalCargoCarried] => 98.673
                            [lastFlightDate] => 30/04/2020
                            [monthFlights] => 0
                            [monthFlightsRegular] => 0
                            [monthFlightsCharter] => 0
                            [monthFlightsEvent] => 0
                            [monthFlightsTour] => 0
                            [monthFlightsTransfer] => 0
                            [monthHoursFlights] => 00:00:00
                            [monthHoursOnline] => 00:00:00
                            [monthMilesFlown] => 0
                            [monthPassengersCarried] => 0
                            [monthPassengersFirstClass] => 0
                            [monthPassengersBusiness] => 0
                            [monthPassengersEconomic] => 0
                            [monthCargoCarried] => 0
                        )

                )
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

*¿Como puedo tomar datos de ese array por separado y luego imprimirlos de la forma mostrada en HTML a continuacion?*

```
<div class="nombre">
            <b id="casillaNombre">Nombre: </b> <?php echo $name; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Se que algo estoy haciendo mal Y MUY MAL. Asi que pido disculpas ante todos los profesionales por las dudas de que vean algo desastrozo ahi dentro y crean que es una falta de respeto ante el lenguaje

Comment: según entiendo no es un array, un objeto, siempre obtendrás un conjunto de datos por petición ?, bueno para los dos casos debes iterar la respuesta, con ayuda de un for() o un foreach() itera el return del consumo, y debes acceder al elemento a través de $iteracion->{nombre elemento}

Comment: Mmm por ejemplo: 
```
foreach ($almacen->name as $name) {
  
 }
```
Es un ejemplo que saque de la documentacion de PHP. Luego de eso lo imprimo con 
```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```? ¿Que crees?

Comment: algo parecido mira aca estoy recorriendo tu peticion, y luego itero nuevamente el result que esta dentro,


foreach ($almacen as $key_almacen => $datos) {
 


 $ernor   = $datos->ernor;
 $created = $datos->created;

 foreach ($result as $key_result => $info) {
  
  $id  = $info->id;
  $name = $info->name;

 }


}

Comment: Me di cuenta que es correcto esto que me estas mostrando. Pero luego cuando lo quiero imprimir en pantalla no imprime nada :(
Supongamos que lo quiero imprimir dentro de dos etiquetas <div> en HTML.

Deberia hacer: `<b>Nombre: </b> <?php echo $name;?>` ?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta pero puede que lo que estés buscando sea [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php)

Comment: Creo que mi problema es que estoy intentando tomar datos del output del array... Creo que eso no se puede hacer. Pero de todas formas tengo muchas dudas con el bucle ```foreach(){}```

Comment: estas  $name = var_dump($almacen[0]["name"]); imprimiendo un var_dump... para que te funcione seria <?php $name; ?> con repecto al foreach($NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE A RECORRER as VARIABLE CONVERTIDA A ARRAY)

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion :D. Pero sigue sin funcionar.. es como que el bucle ´´´foreach(){}´´´ no asigna las variables que quiero a los datos dentro del array. Por ejemplo:

`$almacen = llamadaApi();
foreach ($almacen as $key_array => $datos) {
$ernor = $datos->ernor;
$created = $datos->created;
$result = $datos->result;
foreach ($almacen as $key_result => $info) {
$id = $info->id;
$name = $info->name;
$country = $info->country;
$avatar = $info->avatar;
$imageRating = $info->imageRating;
$ivao = $info->ivao;`

¿que hice mal?

Comment: No se por que se ve tan mal, cabe resaltar que falta un corchete a proposito. Porque es un fragmento de todo el choclo de bucles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Encontre una solución! (Aunque deberé estudiar y averiguar bien el por qué funciona y como interpretar mejor mi codigo).
E aquí mi solución:
Como han mencionado en los comentarios de arriba y en la respuesta del usuario Joel Muñoz Moran; debia recorrer mi array.
Para ello utilicé `foreach(){}`. Esto me permitió guardar cada elemento de mi array en una variable.

```
foreach ($almacen as $key_array => $datos) {
            $ernor = $datos->ernor; 
            $created = $datos->created;
            $result = $datos->result;
                foreach ($datos as $info) {
                    $avatar = $info->avatar; #Aqui como verán accedo al elemento "avatar" y lo guardo en la variable $avatar.
                    $name = $info->name;
                    $country = $info->country;
                    $imageRating = $info->imageRating;
                    $ivao = $info->ivao;
                        
                }
                    foreach ($info as $lentejas) {
                        $totalHoursFlights = $lentejas->totalHoursFlights;
                        $callsign = $lentejas->callsign;    
                        }

        }
```

Aun se me dificulta un poco entender como es que eso funciona en su totalidad y como es que recorre el Array. Pero no se preocupen, voy a investigarlo mejor.
Puedo imprimirlos por separado :D, pero de todas formas hay problemas, eso mejor va en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que necesitas es una [funcion recursiva](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PHP/1406202-Funcion-recursiva-en-PHP.html), dado el contexto que planteas. Si bien la recurrencia es un tema un poco complejo es, de lejos, la mejor manera que tienes para solucionar este problema, debido al nivel de abstracción que podría tener tu respuesta JSON.

Espero que me entiendas:

```
function iterable($haystack){
  if(is_array($haystack) || is_object($haystack)){
    foreach($haystack as $index=> $item){
            if(is_array($item) || is_object($item)){
                echo "\n*{$index}=>";
                foreach($item as $val){
                    print_r(iterable($val).",");
                }
            }else{
                print_r("*".$item);
            }
    }
    }else{
             print_r($haystack);
    }
    
}
```

La funcion recibe por parametro el objeto y empieza a iterar en él; si un elemento hijo es iterable se vuelve a llamar a si mismo para volver a iterar sobre este hasta llegar al nivel mas bajo de abstracción, una vez ahí empieza a mostrar uno a uno los elementos no iterables. Para llamar la función, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
iterable($a);
```

Utilizando este objeto de prueba:

```
$a =  new stdClass();
$a->uno = "dd";
$a->dos_ = array(1,2,3);
$a->tres = array(
    4=>array("4.1","4.2","4.3"),
    5,
    6
    );
```

**Nota:** La recursividad puede causar falta de memoria si no se configura correctamente, obteniendo por respuesta un bucle infinito, ya que la funcion se empujaria a si misma a la pila de llamadas un numero infinito de veces.

Suerte.!

Comment: Esta bien comenzar a declarar variables luego de 
`foreach($item as $val){
                    print_r(iterable($val).",");
                }` 
? Porque estoy haciendo eso y no funciona jejeje. Aca mi codigo por si lo queres ver:

`foreach ($item as $valor) {
    $name = $valor->name;
    echo $name;
    $country = $valor->country;
    $callsign = $valor->callsign;
    $totalHoursFlights = $valor->totalHoursFlights;
    $ivao = $valor->ivao;
   }`

Comment: Puedes... Quizás a nivel sintáctico es correcto, pero no a nivel semantico, me explico: la función que te pase recibirá el objeto JSON y te permitirá obtener todos las propiedades de este objeto, sin importar cuantas colecciones existan en sus propiedades. Si necesitas usar alguna propiedad específica prueba poner: if($index=='country')

Comment: Se me ocurre... pero como te comento la función hará todo por si misma. Si me explicas que deseas hacer con esas propiedades que estas guardando en objetos, tal vez pueda ayudarte, recuerda que incluso puedes declarar variables dinámicamente de esta manera : $$ítem, sin necesidad de concurrir en un problema de redundancia

Comment: Si agregas una captura del resultado que tienes será más fácil detectar el problema, pero a simple vista veo que intentas acceder a la propiedad name de manera incorrecta. Deberías acceder así : result->0->name

Comment: Mira, para dejarlo mas claro: 
Mi idea es tomar valores POR SEPARADO y almacenarlos POR SEPARADO en variables distintas. Para que por ejemplo, pueda usar: `echo $name;` Y que imprima lo que corresponde a `name` dentro del array.
El resultado que imprime es literalmente nada. Es como si no pudiera recorrer el array :(

Comment: Para ser mas especifico aún, quiero imprimir esto dentro del `<body>` De la siguiente forma: `<?php echo $name;>`